# iOS open file in another application - permissions

Tags: iphone, ios, url, file-permissions

I have a file (an Autodesk dwf file to be precise) which I include with my app as a resource.

I would like to open the file in another program using something like [UIApplication openURL:otherapp://path/to/my/file.dwf];

The other app support the custom url scheme. When my code runs, the other app is opened, but the file isn't.

Is this because the file is in my application's resources directory and the other app isn't allowed to "play in that sandbox"? If so, where can I place the file on the phone's file system so that both applications have permission to open it?

Perhaps there's something more fundamental I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: I believe you are exactly right about the permissions issue.  Consider iCloud as a storage location, or a remote server if the file is not modified by the app.  Either of those would probably be a better bet.

Comment: Thanks @nycynik. This is helpful, but I would rather not involve the network.